# How can we search on attribute in a workflow instance in OpenText Content Server 16.0.1?

Tags: opentext

I am configuring workflows in OpenText Content Server 16.0.1. 
I am using very standard and basic features and added a few attributes.
e.g. Division.
I am trying to user the tool capabilities to search on the Division.
None of the out-of-box search tools/screens are able to provide me search results. Can this be achieved only by indexing in this tool? I cant believe that we can't search on workflow attributes.

Regards,
Ashwini Pingle

Comment: On further research, I think I will need to use categories-attribute mapping to achieve this feature. I will try that and post my findings a couple of days later.

Comment: One cannot attach/associate a category to a workflow attribute. Hence this feature did not work. All we can do is to index the custom attributes we add to workflow and then search using System Attribute search.